# SQL Convert String to Integer

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, contactbuilder

In our Marketing Cloud instance we have a column that is a string and needs to be converted to an integer. I have tried the following query but get the following error:

**Query:**

```
   UPDATE TableName
   SET Col_1 = (INT, Col_1)
```

**Error:**

> "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Only
>   SELECT queries are valid. Select must be the first word of the query."

I feel like this is basic SQL capabilities that should be available in marketing cloud, am i missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Nate, SFMC SQL doesn't allow the exact same functionality as you have with regular T-SQL. It's just a subset. Unfortunately, update is not allowed. The only way to update that column is to use the UI and go in and change it in Data Extension properties. You'll have to remove it and add a new column of the same name with the data type you want. You could possible use the API, but that seems like overkil for